# Most efficient way to find an intersection between two sets of numbers encoded with bitwise operations

Tags: c, algorithm, formula

Given two sets of numbers encoded with bitwise operations (using 6 bits for number):

```
 a = {12,20,21,24,31}
 b = {13,18,24,28,35}

 Intersection -> a ∩ b = {24}

 unsigned int a = 0;
 a |= (12 | 20 << 6 | 21 << 12 | 24 << 18 | 31 << 24);

 unsigned int b = 0;
 b |= (13 | 18 << 6 | 24 << 12 | 28 << 18 | 35 << 24);
```

What is the fastest way to find out, if there is at least one number in common between the sets?

This is just an example, but you can have common numbers in any position.

Comment: What are the "sets" in this example? What is the intersection between them?

Comment: Do you mean that the intersection with the example in the question would be `24`, because you have `24` in both `a` and `b` (but at different positions in the word)?

Comment: yes indeed, sorry about that: 12,20,21,24,31 and 13,18,24,28,35 so only 24 is in common, I trying to avoid to do the 25 checks, each one against  each one

Comment: Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt to show us, and describe what problems you have with it.

Comment: @carl please [edit] your question and put all clarifications _there_, as well as an example of input and expected output

Comment: Can you sort the numbers, while encoding?

Comment: @bob__ I guess yes

Comment: Are there always exactly five elements in each set? If not, how do you denote when a set contains more or fewer elements? Are you requiring that all of your target platforms have 32 bits for `unsigned int`, or would you prefer to use `uint32_t` instead?

Comment: So what have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share **YOUR** findings / attempts.

Comment: @Eric, yes always 5 elements in each set, I use 64 bit platform, I have just used unsigned int because the five numbers set in it, I can use unsigned int, uint32_t or uint64_t

Comment: @MrSmith42: Stack Overflow is not *per se* a coaching site. It is a durable repository of questions and answers.

Comment: @MrSmith42, I only tried the 25 comparitions e.g. (f & 0x00000003F) & (f1 & 0x00000003F) etc etc

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>


typedef unsigned int SetType;
#define FieldWidth 6 // Number of bits per field.

#define NumberOfFields (sizeof(SetType) * CHAR_BIT / FieldWidth)


//  Return non-zero iff some element is in both a and b.
int IsIntersectionNonEmpty(SetType a, SetType b)
{
    // Create masks with a bit set for each element an input set.
    uint64_t A = 0, B = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfFields; ++i)
    {
        A |= UINT64_C(1) << (a >> i*6 & 0x3f);
        B |= UINT64_C(1) << (b >> i*6 & 0x3f);
        /*  ">> i*6" moves field i to the low bits.
            "& 0x3f" isolates that six-bit field.
            "UINT64_C(1) << …" generates a 1 bit in that position.
        */
    }

    /* Bitwise AND A and B to see if they have a bit in common, then
       convert that to 1 or 0.
    */
    return !! (A & B);
}
```

Comment: Pretty clever solution taking advantage of the fact that 2^6-1 = 63

Comment: @chux: Yeah, that is on the OP. It is an unstated specification presumed from their example. For readers, `32/6` is the number of bits used to hold the fields divided by the field width. Hence, it is the number of fields being held. Also, they are presumably all occupied—there is no provision for empty/missing values.

Comment: Clever! Something like 51 instructions total.

Comment: It looks great apart from the `uint64_t` to `int` conversion at the end. I suggest `return (A & B) != 0;` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the absolute fastest, but I'd XOR a with b, and see if the result has any six-bit all-zeros pattern in any of your 5 positions. Then shift one of them by 6 bits and repeat up to 4 more times if needed.

Comment: Either way, as long as each element of `a` becomes aligned with each element of `b` during one pass. Actually, thinking about it more, you'll need to go both ways so each `a[i]` aligns with each `b[j]`.

Comment: and that is what I was trying to avoid

Comment: At least it's faster than 25 comparisons because (a) you're comparing 5 elements at once each time, so the reject test is fast, and (b) you only have to do 9 shifts (although you still have to do up to 5 tests of each)

Comment: This does not work, try with `a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` and `b = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`. The XOR doesn't have a single 6-bit field set to 0 yet there is a number in common.

Comment: @marco: you have to shift `a` left by 6 bits up to 4 times, and then right by 6 bits up to 4 times, doing the XOR each time. In your case the `a << 24` result will have the leftmost 6 bits 0.

Comment: @GaryO whoops, you're right, missed that part. Makes sense.

Comment: There's probably some ultra-clever HAKMEM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAKMEM) method for doing this but I can't think of one.

Comment: @GaryO, well let's hope that someone knows one

Comment: @carl: will there be a match most times, or do you expect most of the time to have no match? I.e. which case to optimize for?

Comment: If you're on x86, maybe consider using SSE integer intrinsics -- that way you can operate on up to 8 pairs at a time.

Comment: @GaryO, unpredictable, so I guess no optimization

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat faster version of my solution above; instead of shifting left and right, just rotate:

```c
int leftRotate(unsigned int n, unsigned int d) 
{ 
    return (n << d)|(n >> (32 - d)); 
} 

//  Return non-zero iff some element is in both a and b.
int IsIntersectionNonEmpty(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        unsigned int matches = leftRotate(a, i*6) ^ b;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            unsigned int testval = 0x3f << j*6;
            if (matches & testval == testval)
                return 1; // success
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

5 instructions in the outer loop, 3 in the inner * 5, so 20 total, times 5 loops, around 100 instructions total -- but as soon as it finds a match it returns. So if there are frequent matches it'll likely be faster than the @eric-postpischil version, but with no matches it'll be slower. On the other hand, his solution is likely auto-vectorizable with a smart compiler.

Comment: well this is slower, 0.58 for the first one and 2.25 for the second one on 100000000 tries

Comment: What's the "original"? Some of your code you haven't yet shared, or @eric-postpischil's? I bet his is really fast especially if you let the compiler vectorize.

Comment: the original is the first code provided by Eric Postpischil

Comment: I have mixed up, the first code by Eric Postpischlil is faster than the code provided by GaryO, but the modified code of Eric Postpishclil is slower of his non modified one, I can only do: (f & 0x00000003F) & (f1 & 0x00000003F) || etc etc and it does not even work

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to everyone, but thank to the guy that posted the EL code, I do not know why he withdrew it.
Here we go, as fast as light:

```
 #define EL(x) (UINT64_C(1) << (x)) 
 unsigned int a = 0;
 a |= (12 | 20 << 6 | 21 << 12 | 24 << 18 | 31 << 24);

 unsigned int b = 0;
 b |= (13 | 18 << 6 | 24 << 12 | 28 << 18 | 35 << 24);

 unsigned int aa = EL(a & 0x00000003F) | EL((a & 0x000000FC0) >> 6) | EL((a & 0x3F000) >> 12) | EL((a & 0xFC0000) >> 18) | EL((a & 0x3F000000) >> 24);
 unsigned int bb = EL(b & 0x00000003F) | EL((b & 0x000000FC0) >> 6) | EL((b & 0x3F000) >> 12) | EL((b & 0xFC0000) >> 18) | EL((b & 0x3F000000) >> 24);

 anb = !! (aa & bb);  // intersection
```